# ROS Answers SE migration: ROS fuerte sdf

Tags: ros, gazebo, sdf, xacro, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

I'm trying to switch between ROS electric and ROS fuerte. My problem is in launching the '.launch' file since the shell says that my model is deprecated (originally it was a '.xacro' file).

Does anybody know how to convert it into a new ROS format without rewriting by scratch my model?

Thank you,

Neostek

P.S. I also tried with the 'gzsdf' command following this guide

http://answers.ros.org/question/41766/gazebo-urdf-deprecated/

The real problem is the model misses some parts and the warning message
Warning [parser.cc:348] Gazebo SDF has no gazebo element
Warning [parser.cc:291] DEPRECATED GAZEBO MODEL FILE
On July 1st, 2012, this formate will no longer by supported
continues to appear

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45696/ros-fuerte-sdf/) by [Neostek](https://answers.ros.org/users/2231/neostek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2012-10-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the message you're seeing is a warning, check out this [post](http://answers.ros.org/question/41294/gazebo-with-controller/)

Otherwise, the way to convert from URDF to SDF is a 3 step process.

First, convert the xacro to an urdf using `rosrun xacro xacro.py`.

Then, from [here](https://kforge.ros.org/gazebo/trac/ticket/59),

```
rosrun gazebo urdf2model -f you_model.urdf -o old_gazebo_format.xml
roscd gazebo
source setup.bash
./gazebo/bin/gzsdf print old_gazebo_format.xml > your_model.sdf
```

---

Originally posted by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) with karma: 682 on 2012-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2